# Why do i get address sanitizer:heapbuffer overflow error in my C program using Kadane'?

Tags: c, runtime, heap-memory, kadanes-algorithm

```
    int Kadane(int *a,int n)
    {
        int sum=a[0],max=a[0],i;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            sum=sum+a[i];
            if(sum>max)
                max=sum;
            if(a[i]>max)
                max=a[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    int maxSubarraySumCircular(int* A, int ASize)
    {
        int i,k1,totalsum,k2,maxSum;
        totalsum=0;
        k1=Kadane(A,ASize);
        for(i=0;i<ASize;i++)
        {
            totalsum=totalsum+A[i];
            A[i]=-A[i];
        }
        k2=Kadane(A,ASize);
        maxSum=totalsum+k2;  
        return (maxSum>k1 && maxSum!=0) ? maxSum : k1;
    }
```

When I run this code,it shows me a runtime error of address sanitizer: heap buffer overflow at address:
What did I do there?

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` is suspect. The normal form is `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` (note the **less than n**). I can't be sure.. You need to post the code that is calling the functions.

Comment: More to the point, since you're priming `sum` and `max` with `a[0]`, that loop should probably be `for(int i=1;i<n;i++)`

Comment: To be a bit more clear: We need to know with which arguments you actually call the function `maxSubarraySumCircular()`. Then we be sure where and how the problem actually occurs.

Comment: Resolved it by changing the for loop condition i<n and also i have declared the variable i 2 times ,one in the for loop and the other in the beginning of the function.SO,when I corrected these,I got the output.